# wp_users user_status field

Tags: database

I have found an answer to my question [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-status-of-user_status) but it's 7 years old. I simply want to know if I can use this column for my own purposes.

I'm planning to use the `user_activation_key` column to store a hashed key upon user registration and set an inactive flag in the `user_status` column. This flag will prevent users from logging in until their e-mail address has been verified.

Comment: Hijacking anything in WP, no matter how obsolete and unused it seems, is guaranteed to explode in your face later. Trust me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't used, but to avoid conflicts/problems, other plugins might use it, I'd go with adding a meta to the [wp_usermeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_usermeta) table. There is a set of functions for handling that:

- [add_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)
- [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)
- [update_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)
- [delete_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta)

Shouldn't make a big difference for the functionality you want to implement, but you're on the saver side of things.